# PHP delete cookie not working on safari when open 2 taps

Tags: php, cookies, safari

I delete cookie by command

```
unset($_COOKIE['login']);
setcookie('login', null, -1, '/');
```

It works well when I open 1 tap on safari. But if i open 2 taps it not working.
The cookie not empty. When unserialize($_COOKIE['login']) i get the error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 7 bytes
```

It's ok on Chrome and Firefox.